# Java method calls faster than virtual method calls in C++?

Tags: java, c++, performance, call, virtual

Just stumbled upon this in wikipedia:

> Java can access derived instance methods faster than C++ can access
>   derived virtual methods due to C++'s extra Virtual-Table look-up.
>   However, non-virtual methods in C++ do not suffer from V-Table
>   performance bottlenecks, and thus exhibit performance similar to that
>   of Java.

Is this correct? As far as I know, ALL calls are virtual in Java, and still rely on a virtual table, so my common logic suggests that Java calls cannot possibly be faster than virtual C++ calls.

Am I misinformed or is the article wrong? At any rate - is there a FASTER way of resolving calls at runtime than a virtual table?

Comment: I'm tempted to call BS on that unless it explains how Java handles polymorphic calls. (Which I believe it also uses v-tables.)

Comment: PS Although every compiler I know of uses v-tables, as far as I am aware, the standard doesn't say they have to; they can use whatever method of virtual dispatch they want.

Comment: This is marketing. *Some* calls in Java can be faster than C++ virtual calls, but most calls are not virtual in C++. Then what?

Comment: You would have to work extremely hard to convince me that a vtable lookup in C++, which is just an extra indexed indirection, i.e. one instruction, has a higher cost than anything Java needs to do.

Comment: @EJP - The text is just saying that the fastest function call in Java can be faster than the slowest function call in C++. Marketing speak!

Comment: Like most comparisons of Java and C++, this is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might have to do with optimizations performed by the JIT compilation. In some cases I could imagine the JVM to detect that a certain (virtual) call always refers to a certain implementation and the lookup is not needed.

OTOH, a C++ compiler might also be able to deduce that a lookup is not required in some cases and produce equally good code. Also, virtual functions are not required by C++, so there is the an alternative that Java does not offer.

That said, if you need the functionality that `virtual` offers in C++, there is no generally better alternative I could think of. If you care about performance, just be aware that `virtual` usually does have a cost and that it should only be used where needed.

In general, I find statements like the one you quoted unhelpful and misleading (not your fault, of course).

Comment: To be honest, the whole articles smells of fanboyism all over, very optimistic and over-idealistic.

Comment: There are three kinds of lies in the world - lies, *damn* lies, and benchmarks. Given C++ of sufficiently poor quality, and Java code of sufficiently good quality, I expect it's possible to construct a benchmark which demonstrates Java's runtime "superiority" over C++. And vice versa...

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [source](http://scribblethink.org/Computer/javaCbenchmark.html) for that quote:

> Because the compiler knows which classes are actually loaded and being
>   called, it knows which methods can be de-virtualized and inlined.
>   (Remarkably, modern java compilers also know how to "uncompile"
>   inlined calls in the case where an overriding method is loaded after
>   the JIT compilation happens.)

Though I don't see why a C++ compiler couldn't do that.

Comment: JIT's optimizations work on runtime information, C++ is compiled statically. This difference should favor JVM but it might be that the difference in reality is purely academic.

Comment: What kind of runtime information would be useful during JIT for this?

Comment: JVM knows which classes are really loaded and used. C++ might know only which classes are declared, and this only if doing whole program optimization. Otherwise it doesn't know even that. A whole lot of virtual calls are in fact monomorphic. JVM can easily check that and devirtualize. C++ cannot, because it has no guarantee the call is monomorphic. Moreover, JVM uses inline caches and program specialization to achieve a similar efect that C++ can do with templates.